# How to group the values in foreach by if condition?

Tags: perl

My script like this

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @ar = <DATA>;
for(my $i = 0; $i<=$#ar; $i++){
    $ar[$i] =~m/(\d+)$/g;
    print "$ar[$i]\n" if ($& <= 15);
    print "$ar[$i]\n" if ($& >100);
    print "$ar[$i]\n" if ($& <40 && $& > 15); 
}
__DATA__
hinsa 121
mkzin 12
mkva 34
mvakine 2
mzkev  9
mkvvz 5
mkhvzz 35
```

It gives the outputs but it is not group the value by if condition. and I also try this

```
@ar = <DATA>;
for(my $i = 0; $i<=$#ar; $i++){
    $ar[$i] =~m/(\d+)$/g;
    print "$ar[$i]\n" if ($& <= 15);
}
for(my $v = 0; $v<=$#ar; $v++){
    $ar[$v] =~m/(\d+)$/g;
    print "$ar[$v]\n" if ($& >100);
}
for(my $z = 0; $z<=$#ar; $z++){
    $ar[$z] =~m/(\d+)$/g;
    print "$ar[$z]\n" if ($& <40 && $& > 15); 
}
```

In this code the second for condition is not working.
It gives the output:

```
mkzin 12
mvakine 2
mzkev  9
mkvvz 5

mkva 34
mkhvzz 35
```

I expect output is

```
mkzin 12
mvakine 2
mzkev  9
mkvvz 5
hisa 121
mkva 34
mkhvzz 35
```

How can i do it?
And also please explain, In my script 2 why the second foreach condition is not working?

Comment: If that is your actual code, why don't you fix all these errors first? https://eval.in/220719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hussain: When you write a perl code make sure that you use `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  I have modified your perl code and the problem with your code is you are trying to compare uninitialized `$& value with a number`. So it will throw a warning saying `use of uninitialized $& in numeric gt (>)` at so and so. For that i have modified with a scalar variable as shown below:

**Input File(test.txt):**

```
hinsa 121
mkzin 12
mkva 34
mvakine 2
mzkev  9
mkvvz 5
mkhvzz 35
```

**Code:**

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    #Pass test.txt as an argument to the program
    my $file = $ARGV[0];
    open (my $fh, "<", $file) || die "cant open file";

    my @ar = <$fh>;

   for(my $i = 0; $i<=$#ar; $i++){
          my $temp = 0;
         ($temp) = $ar[$i] =~ m/(\d+)/g;
          print "$ar[$i]\n" if ($temp <= 15);        
        }   

   for(my $v = 0; $v<=$#ar; $v++){
           my $temp = 0;
          ($temp) = $ar[$v] =~ m/(\d+)/g;
          print "$ar[$v]\n" if ($temp > 100);
       }

   for(my $z = 0; $z<=$#ar; $z++){
          my $temp = 0;
         ($temp) = $ar[$z] =~ m/(\d+)/g;
         print "$ar[$z]\n" if ($temp <40 && $temp > 15); 
       }
    close($fh);
```

**Output:**

```
mkzin 12
mvakine 2
mzkev  9
mkvvz 5
hisa 121
mkva 34
mkhvzz 35
```

Comment: You're *assuming* that every regex match is successful.

Comment: I think as per the data it is successful. If there is a input saying "hisa 121 hello" then it will throw a warning. Am i going ri8 or correct me if anything wrong ?

Comment: @mpapec:I have modified the code now.If still something wrong with my code correct me ?

Comment: Yes, you'll get a warning which tells you that something went wrong when dealing with data.

Comment: @Borodin: I think the solution provided by you was extemely good. But Hussain wants to know where exactly he was doing wrong in the second case. So i have modified his code and posted the answer. May be if am going wrong just let me know ?

Comment: Yes @Praveen Some bit of your code is helpful for me as follows ` my $temp = 0;` i can alter my code. But i expect any simple way for my solution like my first case. And thank you Praveen

Comment: @Hussain : I think Borodin have modified the code and placed as per your requirement. It works really good just have a look.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for such convoluted code.

This program works by saving each line of the file into the appropriate element of array `@groups`, and printing the contents once the file has been read.

I hope you realise that lines with a value between 40 and 100 won't be printed at all?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @groups;
while (<DATA>) {
    next unless /(\d+)/;

    my $i;

    $i = 0 if $1 <= 15;
    $i = 1 if $1 > 100;
    $i = 2 if $1 < 40 and $1 > 15;

    push @{ $groups[$i] }, $_ if defined $i;
}

for (@groups) {
   print for @$_;
   print "\n";
}

__DATA__
hinsa 121
mkzin 12
mkva 34
mvakine 2
mzkev  9
mkvvz 5
mkhvzz 35
```

**output**

```
mkzin 12
mvakine 2
mzkev  9
mkvvz 5

hinsa 121

mkva 34
mkhvzz 35
```